# Subprocess Popen : Ignore Accumulo warning and continue execution of Sqoop

Tags: python-2.7, sqoop

I am using Python 2.7. I am trying to execute sqoop command using Python subprocees.Popen to transfer a table to HDFS. Whenever, I do Popen(sqoop_cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE), it is returning with process.poll() status 1.

Looking into the output, I am getting

```
Warning: /opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.9.0-1.cdh5.9.0.p0.21/bin/../lib/sqoop/../accumulo does not exist! Accumulo imports will fail.
Please set $ACCUMULO_HOME to the root of your Accumulo installation.
```

It is not running past this point. But if I run the same command on linux terminal I am get this warning but it continues execution.

```
    Warning: /opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.9.0-1.cdh5.9.0.p0.21/bin/../lib/sqoop/../accumulo does not exist! Accumulo imports will fail.
Please set $ACCUMULO_HOME to the root of your Accumulo installation.
18/03/07 14:41:24 INFO sqoop.Sqoop: Running Sqoop version: 1.4.6-cdh5.9.0
Enter password:
18/03/07 14:41:36 INFO oracle.OraOopManagerFactory: Data Connector for Oracle and Hadoop is disabled.
18/03/07 14:41:36 INFO manager.SqlManager: Using default fetchSize of 1000
18/03/07 14:41:36 INFO tool.CodeGenTool: Beginning code generation
18/03/07 14:41:36 INFO tool.CodeGenTool: Will generate java class as codegen_PRE_TRANSACTION_****.....
```

I think just after it returns warning, the Popen returns with warning code and doesn't execute the whole process.
This is my whole code.

```
        with open(log_file, 'a+') as fh:
          process = subprocess.Popen(sqoop_cmd_list, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
            while True:
                output = process.stdout.readline()
                if output = '' and process.poll() is not None:
                    break
                if output:
                    print output.strip()
                    fh.write(output)
            rc = process.poll()
```

and sqoop_cmd_list is

```
sqoop_cmd_list = ['sqoop',\
                  'import',\
                  '--connect', jdbc_connector,\
                  '--username', \
                  username,\
                  '--password', password,\
                  '--table', table_name,\
                  '--split-by', column_name,\
                  '--target-dir',\
                  '--delete-target-dir',\
                  destination_path,\
                  '--as-parquetfile'
                ]
```

If it stops after returning warning, can I just ignore the warning and continue execution? Or is there any other way I can sqoop using Python?