# Capturing sqoop logs using stdout Popen

Tags: python, subprocess, sqoop, popen

Below is the python code I am running to call sqoop, But this is not capturing the logs except the below few lines

Warning: /usr/hdp/2.6.4.0-91/accumulo does not exist! Accumulo imports will fail.
Please set $ACCUMULO_HOME to the root of your Accumulo installation.

```
import subprocess
job = "sqoop-import --direct --connect 'jdbc:sqlserver://host' --username myuser --password-file /user/ivr_sqoop --table data_app_det  --delete-target-dir   --verbose --split-by attribute_name_id --where \"db_process_time BETWEEN ('2018-07-15') and ('9999-12-31')\""
print job
with open('save.txt','w') as fp:
    proc = subprocess.Popen(job, stdout=fp, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
    stdout, stderr = proc.communicate()
    print "Here is the return code :: " + str(proc.returncode)
    print stdout`
```

Please let me know if there is an issue with the way I am calling.

Note : The individual sqoop cmd is running fine and producing all the logs.

I have tried the below way as well, the result is the same

```
import subprocess
job = "sqoop-import --direct --connect 'jdbc:sqlserver://host' --username myuser --password-file /user/ivr_sqoop --table data_app_det  --delete-target-dir   --verbose --split-by attribute_name_id --where \"db_process_time BETWEEN ('2018-07-15') and ('9999-12-31')\""
proc = subprocess.Popen(job, stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
stdout, stderr = proc.communicate()
```

and also using '2> mylog.log' at the end of the cmd

```
import subprocess
job = "sqoop-import --direct --connect 'jdbc:sqlserver://host' --username myuser --password-file /user/ivr_sqoop --table data_app_det  --delete-target-dir   --verbose --split-by attribute_name_id --where \"db_process_time BETWEEN ('2018-07-15') and ('9999-12-31')\" > mylog.log "
proc = subprocess.Popen(job, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
stdout, stderr = proc.communicate()
```

I have found the below similar question but there was no answer there as well.

[Subprocess Popen : Ignore Accumulo warning and continue execution of Sqoop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49155662/subprocess-popen-ignore-accumulo-warning-and-continue-execution-of-sqoop)

Answer (score 3):

Since you have added `shell=True`, it is not capturing Sqoop logs. Please remove `shell=True` from your command and add `universal_newlines=True`, it will display the console log.

The working piece of code:

```
import subprocess
import logging
logging.basicConfig(format='%(levelname)s:%(message)s', level=logging.DEBUG)
# Function to run Hadoop command
def run_unix_cmd(args_list):
    """
    run linux commands
    """
    print('Running system command: {0}'.format(' '.join(args_list)))
    proc = subprocess.Popen(args_list, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True)
    s_output, s_err = proc.communicate()
    s_return =  proc.returncode
    return s_return, s_output, s_err

# Create Sqoop Job
def sqoop_job():
    """
    Create Sqoop job
    """
    cmd = ['sqoop', 'import', '--connect', 'jdbc:oracle:thin:@//host:port/schema', '--username', 'user','--password', 'XX', '--query', '"your query"', '-m', '1', '--target-dir', 'tgt_dir']
    print(cmd)
    (ret, out, err) = run_unix_cmd(cmd)
    print(ret, out, err)
    if ret == 0:
        logging.info('Success.')
    else:
        logging.info('Error.')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sqoop_job()
```